# Measure the distance from the camera to an object with autofocus

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been looking for a camera property that tells the distance between the camera and the object in focus, but without success.
Considering the phone has autofocus, one should be able to tell the distance simply by checking the focal length. Also the taken images taken has the following properties, which both should be what I'm looking for:

kCGImagePropertyExifFocalLength

kCGImagePropertyExifSubjectDistance

Is there a way to see these properties already in the camera without taking the picture?

Comment: what do you want to use this for?

Comment: It's a little app idea I had where I simply, in a fairly flexible way, need to decide the distance at a medium distance pretty fast, pretty accurate. I know about the pythagoran theorem method, but I've found on other apps that it doesn't work too well if not in optimal environments.

Comment: It won't be accurate, especially in bright light, because of hyperfocal distance.  Any lens at a certain f-stop will have a distance beyond which all objects are in focus.  This is how simple cameras without autofocus can take clear pictures on bright days.

Comment: Ahh that's a bummer... Do you know if it's possible to fetch the property though (the curiosity of a naive youth)? It's obviously there. The question is mainly whether or not it's made available for use.

Comment: As far as I can tell those are image properties, not camera properties, so you can only get them after you take a picture.  iOS8 is supposed to add a whole new bunch of camera controls.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Guess i'll just have to wait then.